# Table cells not aligned in Firefox, IE

Tags: html, css, browser, html-table

I'm trying to create a table whose first column is fixed. I have done that somehow but i'm not able to get the same result across all the browsers. The result is correct only on Chrome. This is the result I'm getting on Firefox/IE 8:

[image]

and that on Chrome:

[image]

Here is my HTML code:

```
<div id="riassuntoOreTecnico">

<table id="riassuntoOreTecnicoTable" >
    <tr>
        <th>Technician Name</th>
        <td style="padding-left:165px"></td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>
        <th>Table Cell</th>
        <td style="padding-left:165px"></td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>
        <td>Table Cell</td>

        <td>Table Cell</td>
    </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

And the CSS:

```
#riassuntoOreTecnico {
    width: 94%;
    float: left;
    margin: 30px 35px;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: visible;
}

#riassuntoOreTecnicoTable {
/*  border-collapse: separate;*/
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    float: left;
}

#riassuntoOreTecnicoTable th {
    background: #d5d5d5;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 8px;
    position: absolute;
    top:auto;
    width:158px;
}

#riassuntoOreTecnicoTable td {
    border: 1px solid #d5d5d5;
    padding: 5px 8px;
}
```

Can anyone suggest whats wrong here with my code so i can get the same result on firefox/IE8 as well?

Comment: Seems fine when putting your code in a fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/MrqD7/

Comment: Thats the problem. Its the same code but i dont understand why is there a problem with latest firefox or something.

Comment: It's fine in FF using the fiddle.

Comment: Just a piece of advice - Are you using a reset stylesheet? If not you should do to help avoid things like this.

Comment: Thanks for the advise Alex but i'm not using reset stylesheet. Actually in the CSS for `table` i added `white-space:nowrap` for this table i just tried changing it and that worked.

Comment: Strongly, STRONGLY, advise that you add a [reset stylesheet](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), otherwise you'll be seeing more inconsistencies across browsers like this.

Comment: @alex Noted!! will do so :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added `white-space:normal` to the table CSS and that fixed it for me.

Here is the updated code:

```
#riassuntoOreTecnicoTable {
/*  border-collapse: separate;*/
    border: 1px solid #ddd;
    float: left;
    white-space:normal
}
```

Thank you all.

Comment: Just a piece of advice - Are you using a reset stylesheet? If not you should do to help avoid things like this.